# What is the purpose of .yo-repository directory created with code generated by yeoman?

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator, yo

I was using a code generator that uses yeoman underneath. Recently, suddenly, started generating a `.yo-repository` directory.

I can't find what that is by a quick Google search.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

it looks that they are using this folder for installing packages. Check the yeoman-environment library here:

https://github.com/yeoman/environment/blob/4e75d3692ede9205118737b9522c3514faaaef5f/lib/util/repository.js#L173